# After updation on W10M

Tags: discussion, support, editing

I asked a [question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/13713/how-to-use-dual-whatsapp-in-lumia-535) when I was on WP8. and the activities on this question make me to think that its not possible on WP8.1. I also have accepted an answer there which states that its impossible. Now I have updated on W10M and still need the answer of the question if it is possible for W10M. What should I do edit that question or ask a new one with the same content replacing WP8.1 with W10M?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my personal opinion, lets us have two questions, but with appropriate titles such as ***How to use dual whatsapp in WP 8.1?*** and ***How to use dual whatsapp in W10M?*** instead of the current title *How to use dual whatsapp in Lumia 535*.

I suggest this because your question has been asked for WP 8.1 and it already has an answer for it. There still may be persons who may look for ways to install dual whatsapp in WP8.1. Starting a seperate question for Windows 10 would be good. But don't forget to

1. Link the old question from new one so that they will appeared as linked questions.
2. Change the title to OS specific ones.

Also wait for other member's opinions.

Comment: I have specified OS in title. Waiting for more responses. +1 for a very logical answer.

Comment: Done..... but how to link the old question from new one so that they will appeared as linked questions?

Comment: @User5 Questions will be linked automatically if their URL is mentioned. In your case, the questions are already linked. See the right side of our question(above your related question).