# Triplet of questions

Tags: discussion, questions, exact-duplicates

So , [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/13713/how-to-use-dual-whatsapp-in-lumia-535-running-wp8-1?noredirect=1&lq=1) I asked about dual WhatsApp for WP8.1. Then, with reference to [this](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361/after-updation-on-w10m) question I made the same attempt for W10M [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/14521/how-to-use-dual-whatsapp-in-w10m). Now I found that there's a similar question [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/11801/how-to-install-og-whatsapp-in-windows-phone?rq=1) which asks about OG WhatsApp. Now there are three questions talking about the same. So What should we do? Link them together or declare one as an exact duplicate of other?

**Note**:

For fellows who don't know much about android platform, I would say here that OG WhatsApp is basically a third-party android app which installs on the device with an address and name which is different from original WhatsApp enabling users to run multiple WhatsApp accounts separately without any sort of interference. I am including this detail into the question because the behavior of users made me to think that they don't know about OG WhatsApp.